# Google Maps V3 with MarkerCluster changing the color rules

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

Using Google Maps V3 with MarkerCluster, you can see three different types of colors when clusertering, based on how many is clustered toghter.

Problem:
I want to change the rule from based on how many, to how serious the case is on that area, its also represented in the custom icons I use. The types im working with is green for a good running product, yellow for a warning and red for a bad product.

I want to be able to see the red color on the cluster icon if there is a bad product in there somewhere, and not at all based on the number..

Im using ASP.NET MVC3 with razor - that maybe could help.

Can this be done guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume:

- your cluster image files are in place and have indexes of 1-green; 2-yellow; 3-red;
- references to your marker icons (string|Icon|Symbol) are made available as properties of the object, `markerIcons`

```
var markerIcons = {
    'green': '...',
    'yellow': '...',
    'red': '...'
};
```

Then, you can control which cluster icons are displayed with a calculator function as follows :

```
var myClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, {
    ...,//options
});

mc.setCalculator(function(markers, numStyles) {
    var index = 1;//green
    loop:
    for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
        switch(markers[i].getIcon()) {
            case markerIcons.yellow:
                index = 2;//yellow
            break;
            case markerIcons.red:
                index = 3;//red
                break loop;
            break;
        }
    }
    var index = Math.min(index, numStyles);
    return {text:markers.length, index:index};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change calculator function:

```
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map);

mc.setCalculator(
    function(markers, numStyles) {
        return {text: markers.length, index: 8}; 
     }
 );
```

The function get list of markers and should return a pair : text label and the colour number.